# Can this object reference counter be replaced with shared_ptr (or some smart pointer)?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, reference-counting

Here's an example program which emulates a "hot potato". The `Potato` object gets created and can be passed around through copying, moving, etc. and once the Potato finally gets destroyed without getting passed along, it exits the program.

#### [Live code](http://cpp.sh/737rln)

I accomplished this by giving each *new* potato a unique ID and using a singleton potato manager (`PotatoFarm`) to keep track of reference counts. Every time `Potato` is constructed or copied, I increment the reference count. Each time it is destroyed, I decrement the reference count, and once it hits zero, I "drop" the potato.

```cpp
class Potato {
public:
    using Id = std::size_t;

    // new potato, assign new id and increment ref count
    Potato() : _id(PotatoFarm::get().nextId()) {
      PotatoFarm::get().incRefCt(_id);
    }

    // copied potato, just increment ref count
    Potato(const Potato& p) : _id(p._id) {
      PotatoFarm::get().incRefCt(_id);
    }

    // dtor, decrement and check reference count
    ~Potato() {
        if (PotatoFarm::get().decChkRefCt(_id)) { // returns true when ref ct reaches 0
          std::cout << "dropped the hot potato\n";
          exit(1);
        }
    }

    // Example of a method that possibly mutates Potato and returns the object back
    Potato passthru() {
        std::cout << "passing thru\n";
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Id _id;
};
```

The singleton manager:

```cpp
class PotatoFarm {
public:
  using Id = std::size_t;
  PotatoFarm() : _next(0) {}
  // get singleton instance
  static PotatoFarm& get() {
      static PotatoFarm s_obj;
      return s_obj;
  }
  Id nextId() { return _next++; }
  // reference counting of Potatoes by id
  std::size_t incRefCt(Id id) { return ++_refCt[id]; }
  bool decChkRefCt(Id id) { // return true when 0
      if (--_refCt[id] == 0) {
        _refCt.erase(id);
        return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
private:
  Id _next;
  std::unordered_map<Id, std::size_t> _refCt;
};
```

And the code that passes the potato around:

```cpp
Potato bar() {
    std::cout << "in bar\n";
    return Potato();
}

Potato foo() {
    std::cout << "in foo\n";
    Potato hp = bar().passthru();
    std::cout << "after bar\n";
    return hp;
}

int main(void) {
    Potato hp = foo();
    std::cout << "after foo\n"; // this should be printed!
    // but the return code of the program should be 1
    return 0;
}
```

This returns, as desired:

```
in foo
in bar
passing thru
after bar
after foo
dropped the hot potato
```

Rather than creating my own reference counter, can this be simplified just by passing around a smart pointer?

Comment: You could make `Potato` movable but not copyable, then you won't need reference counter at all.

Comment: I tried that, but ran into the same problem as you did before deleting the comment. Kept getting "dropped" before getting back to main(). This will be something used by other programmers, so I'm also trying to keep it simpler on them, as long as it's being "passed", it should stay alive. If you have a way around that, I'm all ears! That's even more elegant than smart pointers. Thank you!

Comment: [This works](http://cpp.sh/32345). The problem in the first attempt was simply that I didn't realize `_id` was unsigned, and checked `_id >= 0` in destructor. You just need some way - any way - to mark moved-from `Potato` instance (a cold potato?) as safe to be destroyed.

Comment: You don't even need an ID (and without it, could get rid of `PotatoFarm`) unless you want it for some other purpose. Just a boolean `is_hot` would suffice.